# How to reduce a string containing the same substring repeated n times to a single instace of the substring

Tags: php, string

I have strings like `'ageage'` or `'feetfeetfeet'` or `'cmcmcmcmcm'` and would like to reduce these to `'age'`, `'feet'`, and `'cm'` respectively.

This is an intermediate step in normalization for matching across different data sources of certain classes of data fields that originally also contained numbers. The numeric parts have been removed into a separate string. All the unicode letters have been transliterated to  lowercase ASCII letters with:

```php
public static function transliterate(string $value)
{
    $transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules(
        ':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: Lower(); :: NFC;',
        Transliterator::FORWARD
    );
    return $transliterator->transliterate($value);
}
```

Also note that pluralization doesn't matter because while the examples I've provided are in English the project is normalizing mainly Turkish strings where such words would always be singular.

I expect this can be done with regex. Though I'm not entirely sure how

Comment: Interesting problem. And interesting that everything is in singular? Really? Is that Turkish or just your problem? Anyways, can there not be a word that repeats itself. In lack of better examples `reread`.

Comment: If you're positive all strings will only ever contain a single string, or repetitions thereof, this is relatively easy to solve (though I wouldn't use regex). Simply iterate character by character and watch for a recurrence, then truncate where the recurrence begins, discard the rest.

Comment: @Andreas This is for part of a function for normalizing strings like `11 years - 12 years` to `11-12years`. In English (and probably most indo-European languages) it would be `1 year - 2 years` but in Turkish the numerically qualified nouns are always singular so `1 year - 2 year` is correct.  There are actually words that consist of repetetions themselves, which is something I had not considered. Though reread should not be a problem, mm (short for milimeter) presents a problem, that actually proves I will probably have to solve this another way.

Comment: @MarkusAO I don't think that would always work. Consider the example input provided by @Andreas: `reread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This looks similar to finding longest common prefix which is also a suffix. Now, the `length - longest prefix which is also a suffix` is your answer. You can find the algorithm of building the prefix suffix table from this [`KMP pattern matching algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).
- Time complexity is `O(n)` and space complexity is `O(n)`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = "feetfeetfeet";
$length = strlen($str);

$prefix_suffix_table = array_fill(0, $length, 0);

$j = 0;
for($i = 1; $i < $length; ++$i){
    while($j > 0 && $str[$i] != $str[$j]){
        $j = $prefix_suffix_table[$j - 1];
    }

    if($str[$i] == $str[$j]){
        $prefix_suffix_table[$i] = ++$j;
    }
}

echo substr($str, 0, $length - end($prefix_suffix_table));
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b401c75cde38a51a561b53bb0a6294eb615b208c

**Note:** If your string is malformed like `xyz` which doesn't have a repeating substring, you can just add an additional check using `str_repeat()` and throw an exception if required.

Answer (score 2):

I assume non regex is ok.

This method loops through half the string and tries to find a substring that if used in a str_replace returns nothing.
If we find that then the know it's a repeating word.

```
$str = 'feetfeetfeet';
$return = $str; // return full str if it fails

$len = strlen($str);

for($i = 1; $i < $len/2; $i++){
    $sub = substr($str, 0, $i);
    if(str_replace($sub, "", $str) == ""){
        $return = $sub;
        break;
    }
}

echo $return; //feet
```

Comment: No.. that is a mistake, I actually write in the text "loops through half the string" but I forgot `/2`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `str_split()` to convert the string into array and find its unique elements and then again return implode all the unique elements together.

```
<?php
$str = array_unique(str_split('ageage'));
$result = implode($str);
?>
```

**Output**

```
age
```

Comment: What happens with `feetfeetfeet`? Or for that matter `Mississippi`?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do this with a regex. Even though I have realized that it might not be useful for my purposes because mmmm can be both 2x mm (millimeter) or 4x m (meters). Though If I only care about supporting up to 3 repetitions I can use:

```
if(preg_match('/^([a-z]*)\1{2}$/', $input, $matches)) {
    $repeating = $matches[1];
    $reps = 3;
} elseif(if(preg_match('/^([a-z]*)\1$/', $input, $matches)) {
    $repeating = $matches[1];
    $reps = 2;
} else {
    $repeating = $input;
    $reps = 1;
}
```

Not that the following will divide the string into the smallest prime number of repeats:

```
preg_match('/^([a-z]*)\1+$/', $input, $matches);
$repeating = $matches[1];
```

Here is a table of the outputs of this:

```
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│   $input   │ $repeating │
├────────────┼────────────┤
│ mm         │ m          │
│ mmm        │ m          │
│ mmmm       │ mm         │
│ mmmmm      │ m          │
│ mmmmmm     │ mmm        │
│ mmmmmmm    │ m          │
│ mmmmmmmm   │ mmmm       │
│ mmmmmmmmm  │ mmm        │
│ mmmmmmmmmm │ mmmmm      │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

Because only the smalles prime subdivisions are considered

```
preg_match('/^([a-z]*)\1{1,2}$/', $input, $matches)
```

is unsuitable as it will, like in the above table, find the repeating part of 'mmmmmm' to be 'mmm' instead of the desired mm.

The three case implementation I have provided at the beginning is what I am currently using because my input is generally either age groups or dimensions for products and I have yet to see a product be described with more than three dimensions or with an age group like `'11yr,12yr,13yr,14yr'` though I can imagine something like the latter, however rare, eventually occurring. Thus I will probably move away from this method and switch to extracting the units from the original string containing the numbers with preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]+)\s*([a-z]*)\s*/', $input, $matches)
```

However in case someone else is actually interested in finding the smallest repeating substring (so 'm' for 'mmmm') this can be done with a regex in a loop:

```
$repeating = $input;
while(preg_match('/^([a-z]*)\1+$/', $repeating, $matches)) {
    $repeating = $matches[1];
}
```

This will produce:

```
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│   $input   │ $repeating │
├────────────┼────────────┤
│ mm         │ m          │
│ mmm        │ m          │
│ mmmm       │ m          │
│ mmmmm      │ m          │
│ mmmmmm     │ m          │
│ mmmmmmm    │ m          │
│ mmmmmmmm   │ m          │
│ mmmmmmmmm  │ m          │
│ mmmmmmmmmm │ m          │
│ cmcm       │ cm         │
│ cmcmcm     │ cm         │
│ cmcmcmcm   │ cm         │
│ cmcmcmcmcm │ cm         │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```